# similar to Editor can create any new user except administrator

Tags: user-roles

I have set up a WP multi-site with custom roles. One of the roles can add users. I need a solution to only show two roles available to the limited role on add user and leave all user types available to administrator. [This code snipped](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/editor-can-create-any-new-user-except-administrator) works great for removing Administrator mode, but I don't understand enough of it to know if I could expand it to exclude other roles as well. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Simple all you need to do is edit this part of the code :

```
function editable_roles( $roles ){
    if( isset( $roles['administrator'] ) && !current_user_can('administrator') ){
      unset( $roles['administrator']);
    }
    return $roles;
  }
```

and change it to

```
function editable_roles( $roles ){
    //don't change anything if current user is admin 
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
        return;
    }else{
        if( isset( $roles['administrator'] ) && !current_user_can('administrator') ){
           unset( $roles['administrator']);
           //here you add  "unset( $roles['role_to_remove']);" for each role you wish to remove
        }
    return $roles; 
  }
```

Comment: YOU are awesome!  thanks a BUNCH - worked like a charm

Comment: Glad i can help

Comment: could this be used without the JPB_User_Caps class & in the functions.php?

Comment: Yep its WordPress functions so you should be able to use them in your functions.pho