# Prevent Editors from Editing/Deleting Admin Accounts

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I need editors to be able to add/edit/delete other users. Giving them those capabilities is easy with code similar to this:

```
$editor = get_role('editor');
$editor->add_cap('edit_users');
```

The problem is that when they have the privileges they need to add/edit/delete other users, they can also do all of those things to admin users and/or promote themselves to the admin role.

Is there a way to allow them to add/edit/delete only specified user roles (best case scenario)? Or as an alternative, prevent editors from doing anything at all to admin accounts, and possibly even hide those accounts from their list view altogether?

Answer (score 2):

There is a function WordPress uses called `get_editable_roles`, which is (I think) used to determine which roles a particular user can edit. The source for this function looks like this:

```
function get_editable_roles() {
    global $wp_roles;

    $all_roles = $wp_roles->roles;
    $editable_roles = apply_filters('editable_roles', $all_roles);

    return $editable_roles;
}
```

So, it looks like you may be able hook into the *editable_roles* filter to get what you're looking for. Something like this:

```
function wpse_80220_filter( $roles ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( in_array( 'editor', $current_user->roles ) ) {
        unset( $roles['administrator'] );
    }

    return $roles;
}
add_filter( 'editable_roles', 'wpse_80220_filter' );
```

I haven't tested any of the above code, but play with it and let me know if it does the trick!

Comment: Nice filter! But it only prevents the Administrator role from appearing in the roles dropdown list, admins are still listed in the users list. I guess a [`pre_user_query`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/10748/12615) will finish the job ;)