# Remove Adminstrator Hyperlink from a user having role to add and see users

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I have create a user role using Advance Access Manager wordpress plugin having role to see, add and remove users name as site_admin. When user login with his Id he is able to see the adminstrator and edit his profile. I remove that thing by using this code.

[Remove Ability for Other Users to View Administrator in User List?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10742/remove-ability-for-other-users-to-view-administrator-in-user-list)

But the problem is the 'Adminstrator' hyperlink is still there. I want to remove that 'Adminstrator' hyperlink and in 'All' hyperlink the total count should be all user except the Adminstrator.

It shows

`All(3) | Adminstrator(1)| Subscriber(1) | site_admin(1)`

I want to remove 'Adminstrator' Hyperlink from this links and set count for 'All(2)'. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work just fine:

```
function my_views_users($args) {
    $hidden_role = 'administrator';  // it will hide filter with role 'administrator' - you can change it to some other role

    $users_counts = count_users();
    $total_users = $users_counts['total_users'] - $users_counts['avail_roles'][$hidden_role];

    $args['all'] = "<a href='$url'$class>" . sprintf( _nx( 'All <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'All <span class="count">(%s)</span>', $total_users, 'users' ), number_format_i18n( $total_users ) ) . '</a>';
    unset($args[$hidden_role]);
    return $args;
}
add_filter('views_users', 'my_views_users');
```

Of course you should add some if statement to disable this code, when user is logged in as admin (you don't want to hide users from admin, I guess).