# Prevent Admin user to edit/see super admin from users list

Tags: users, capabilities

How do I hide my super admin from the users list?
My client has to be the ability to create users, but not edit/see my super admin user.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend the following:

The Editor user role in WordPress cannot by default edit users. You may want to add that capability for clients whom you keep as 'Editors'. This will let the Editor add new users (create new users), delete users, and edit users. This is done by adding capabilities to the Editor role with '`add_cap`'.

> ### This lets Editors manage users

```
function wpse104808_editor_manage_users() {

    if ( get_option( 'wpse104808_add_cap_editor_once' ) != 'done' ) {

        // let editor manage users

        $edit_editor = get_role('editor'); // Get the user role
        $edit_editor->add_cap('edit_users');
        $edit_editor->add_cap('list_users');
        $edit_editor->add_cap('promote_users');
        $edit_editor->add_cap('create_users');
        $edit_editor->add_cap('add_users');
        $edit_editor->add_cap('delete_users');

        update_option( 'wpse104808_add_cap_editor_once', 'done' );
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse104808_editor_manage_users' );
```

---

> ### Prevent Editor From Deleting Administrator User
>
> *This will stop Editors from deleting, editing, or adding new Administrators.*

```
class wpse104808_user_caps {

  // Add our filters
  function wpse104808_user_caps(){
    add_filter( 'editable_roles', array(&$this, 'editable_roles'));
    add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', array(&$this, 'map_meta_cap'),10,4);
  }
  // Remove 'Administrator' from the list of roles if the current user is not an admin
  function editable_roles( $roles ){
    if( isset( $roles['administrator'] ) && !current_user_can('administrator') ){
      unset( $roles['administrator']);
    }
    return $roles;
  }
  // If someone is trying to edit or delete an
  // admin and that user isn't an admin, don't allow it
  function map_meta_cap( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ){
    switch( $cap ){
        case 'edit_user':
        case 'remove_user':
        case 'promote_user':
            if( isset($args[0]) && $args[0] == $user_id )
                break;
            elseif( !isset($args[0]) )
                $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
            $other = new WP_User( absint($args[0]) );
            if( $other->has_cap( 'administrator' ) ){
                if(!current_user_can('administrator')){
                    $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'delete_user':
        case 'delete_users':
            if( !isset($args[0]) )
                break;
            $other = new WP_User( absint($args[0]) );
            if( $other->has_cap( 'administrator' ) ){
                if(!current_user_can('administrator')){
                    $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return $caps;
  }

}

$wpse104808_custom_role = new wpse104808_user_caps();
```

> ### Hide Administrator From User List
>
> *Here are 3 variations to hide users from the Users list. Choose 1 of the following.*

#### *Option 1: Hide specific users from user list.*

If you want to choose individual IDs to hide from the User list, use this (replace '`2,5,7,9`' the User IDs which you want to hide)

```
add_action('pre_user_query','wpse104808_pre_user_query');
function wpse104808_pre_user_query($user_search) {

    $admin_ids = '2,5,7,9'; // REPLACE THESE NUMBERS WITH IDs TO HIDE.

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $admin_array = explode($admin_ids, ',');
    if ( ! in_array( $user->ID, $admin_array ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1', "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID NOT IN($admin_ids)",$user_search->query_where);

    }
}
```

---

#### *Option 2: Hide all administrators from user list.*

```
// Hide all administrators from user list.

add_action('pre_user_query','wpse104808_pre_user_query');
function wpse104808_pre_user_query($user_search) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {

        global $wpdb;

        $user_search->query_where = 
            str_replace('WHERE 1=1', 
            "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID IN (
                 SELECT {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
                    WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = '{$wpdb->prefix}capabilities'
                    AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value NOT LIKE '%administrator%')", 
            $user_search->query_where
        );

    }
}
```

---

Related links:
- [Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)
- [`add cap`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap)
- [`WP_Role::add_cap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/add_cap/)
- [`WP_User::add_cap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/add_cap/)

Comment: Upvoted for the detailed answer, but you probably need much more capabilities to make an editor a sub admin. It would probably be better to have dedicated role for that instead of making all editors sub admins.

Comment: Thanks @MarkKaplun, appreciated. I totally agree with you, just wanted to share a simple possible solution/workaround. This is how I setup most of my clients websites, since I'm in charge of maintenance this works for me. ;)

Comment: That information is great and very useful as a base to start playing around with custom roles. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should help you, I guess (only make sure you're hiding proper user):

[Remove Ability for Other Users to View Administrator in User List?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10742/remove-ability-for-other-users-to-view-administrator-in-user-list)

Also look at this one:

[Remove Adminstrator Hyperlink from a user having role to add and see users](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97309/remove-adminstrator-hyperlink-from-a-user-having-role-to-add-and-see-users/103620#103620)

Comment: Please consider flagging question as possible duplicate rather than make link only answer.

Comment: I don't think duplicate will be helpful in this case, because you need at least these 2 questions to do it. This site is to help others, not to flag and close, I guess... But maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: the help also includes keeping site clean and easy to search. :) Answers with nothing but link are considered too curt because they do not elaborate how that answers the question and links tend to die. Not saying you _had_ to flag in this specific case, just noting for your information.

Comment: I fully agree, but this case is bad example, I guess. It's not a duplicate of one question... And I'm pretty sure that dying links are not the problem here either ;)